# Simple pattern rule in make

Tags: bash, makefile

I've written a simple make to test with pattern rule. Here it is:

```
default:
    echo This is default target
%.o:%.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

I have a three *.c files in `pwd`. After `make` command I have:

```
echo This is default target
This is default target
```

but I expected that any `*.c` file in `pwd` will be compiled.

Comment: do you mean you source files are NOT compiled?

Comment: Are you expecting the default to go through all the targets?  As it stands, if you want to compile foo.c you should be typing `make foo.o` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first target in the `makefile` is the one that is built when you do not specify a specific target name.

In your `makefile`, `default` is first, so it is created.

Often, you'll create a target `all` as the first target, and list the programs that should be built by some more or less devious means.

```
.PHONY: default all clean

default:
    @echo "You must specify which program you want built (or specify all)"

SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
PROGS = ${SRCS:.c=}

all: ${PROGS}

%.o:%.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

The `.PHONY` target specifies that `default`, `all` and `clean` are not real files but [phony targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

I have a directory with many source files in it, and I have a default rule similar to the above as the first target, but I also have an `all` target so that `make all` works sensibly.

I prefer to use the `${...}` notation around `make` variables, which `make` has always accepted; many people use `$(...)` notation the whole time.

Comment: I also think the OP's makefile even can NOT create target `default`? I'm NOT sure if he want to create target or NOT, in my answer, it will generate `default` as the program target, am I right?

Comment: It's a phony target, like `all` and `clean` are too.

Comment: OK, may be I got the point, OP do NOT want to create any real target?

Comment: That's it.  I've added the explicit `.PHONY` rule to declare that.

Comment: further question, WHY `$(...)` is bad?

Comment: I didn't say `$(...)` is bad; I just don't use it except where coding standards dictate otherwise.  I prefer the `${...}` notation because that's what the shell uses, even though the connections between shell and `make` variables are tenuous.

Answer (score 0):

I think `default` is your program target, but it did not link any objects? see my makefile:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

default:
    @echo This is default target
Program: $(OBJS)
    gcc $^ -o $@
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    gcc -c $^
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(Program)
```

if you type `make`, it just `echo` `This is default target`, if you want to make real target, you can type `make Program`